# How to find out if a number ends in .5 or .0

Tags: java, module, numbers

I was just wondering if you guys could help me out with a problem?.

```
double num = 2.0

if(num%1 != 0)
{
   System.out.println("hi");


}
else if(num%.5 != 0)
{
   System.out.println("hi there");


}
```

basically i want to make sure a number the user enters ends with .0 or .5.....but i am having trouble figuring it out. The above "solution" is what i came up with but it doesnt seem to work. Any pointers?, im relatively new to programming by the way so any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Comment: `2.0` is just a divisible by `0.5` as `2.5` is. You need to `%1 == 0.5`.

Answer (score 7):

The `%` operator works on the floating-point types `float` and `double` as well as the integral types in Java.  Any number that ends in ".0" or ".5" is divisible by `0.5`.

```
if (num % 0.5 == 0)
{
    System.out.println("Ends in .0 or .5!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    if (num - Math.rint(num) == 0) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    } else if (Math.abs(num - Math.rint(num)) == 0.5) {
        System.out.println("hi there");
    }
```